# How to ignore unassigned new in ReSharper?

Tags: c#, comments, resharper

(Using ReSharper Ultimate 2017.1.3.)

In my code I have something like this:

```
new someClass(null);
```

It is not assigned to any variable and it should stay like this. (It may look weird but it is used in a specific test case.)

ReSharper warning says:

> Possible unassigned object create by 'new' expression

The menu doesn't suggest to auto-write the comment so I'm looking for the syntax.

What is the ReSharper comment to ignore this?

After some search I already tried:

```
// ReSharper disable once

// ReSharper disable once UnassignedField

// ReSharper disable once UnassignedField.Compiler
```

Comment: "It is not assigned to any variable and it should stay like this." - actually, I'm going to side with resharper here... it sounds like you're using the constructor in a very inappropriate way, that frankly should be changed.

Comment: btw; another common trick for making tools happy about "unused" values is: `GC.KeepAlive({your statement});` - this doesn't actually keep anything "alive" - it is just a deliberately opaque method that does a `pop`

Comment: It is in a test case which tests that constructor returns ArgumentNullException when given null parameter. Otherwise, I don't decide the company's code syntax and practices. (just added the "null" parameter which I had forgotten in original post)

Comment: In production code I would struggle to find a good reason to do so, but there really isn't an alternative for something like a test case for Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(()=>new Foo(null)); You could assign it to a variable but it would then complain of an unused variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place this line directly above the unassigned new, you can disable the warning once.

```
// ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism.

Comment: Not a problem. I try to write in a positive way and think about the other person. :)  Wishing you well.