# Make ReSharper/Roslyn/Compiler recognize JsonRequiredAttribute

Tags: c#, json.net, resharper, roslyn-code-analysis, c#-8.0

Sometimes, when you create DTOs to deserialize `json`, you decorate properties with the `[JsonRequiredAttribute]`:

```cs
class Car
{
    [JsonRequired]
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

However, when you do this while using ReSharper or C# 8 you'll see the following warning:

> Car.cs(30, 19): [CS8618] Non-nullable property 'Make' is uninitialized. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

In some projects I have a lot of such warnings and I was wondering if there is a way to suppress them only for false-positives? I could disable them completely but I'd rather not to.

Comment: Can you just initialize Make to an empty string?

Comment: It should be possible [to disable specific warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838112/1997232) for next line using *once*, not sure in error, try `CS8618`?

Comment: You can try to decorate the property with `[NotNull]` attribute or init by an empty string

Comment: @MichaelLiu this would look like a property had a default value. It would work for some of them but in many cases there is no resonable value I could provide. I'm not sure about that solution. It's not just a string, there can be dictionaries, lists, all kinds of stuff, also interfaces or other abstract types.

Comment: Actually, it's not resharper warning, those you can disable [normally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726795/1997232), but that would be more work than fixing problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using C# 8, you could use the [Null Forgiving Operator](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification.md#the-null-forgiving-operator). For example,

```
public string Make { get; set; } = null!;
```

From the docs

> The postfix ! operator has no runtime effect - it evaluates to the
>   result of the underlying expression. Its only role is to change the
>   null state of the expression, and to limit warnings given on its use.

Comment: I've tried this out with my `TryDoSomething` methods and this is also useful for `out T value` parameters because there the compiler also warns about possible null assignment. Or just returning `default!` in empty implementations.